# Need help formatting output C++

Tags: c++

My function to display a division table is working, but I want to format the output to allow any number of character preceding the decimal, but limiting the after decimal places to 2. Here is the code I am working with. Once I added the line `cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield)` my data appears to be formatted correctly, but I am getting extra numbers appended to the front of the actual number.
so instead of printing `1.00`, the program prints `40981.00`, and it does this for all the results. (the preceding number does change to `4102x.xx`) x being the desired output.

```
void print_div_values(mult_div_values ** table, float x, float y){

cout << endl << "Here is the division table: " << endl;

for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++)        
{
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++)    
    {
        cout << std::setw(5) << cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield) << std::setprecision(2) << table[i][j].div;        
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Wouldn't a copy-paste do, why waste space?

Comment: Yes, sorry will do that next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::ostream::setf` returns the old flags, which are then formatted as an integer by `cout`. Use

```
cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
cout << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(2) << table[i][j].div;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So my problem was the order and trying to do too many things in one line?

Comment: Sort of. If you want to do it in one line, you can write `cout << setw(5) << setfixed << setprecision(2) << table[i][j].div;` It's just that `ostream::setf` returns a number, and that was then printed; it's not a manipulator like the others.